# Complete reinstall python, pycharm, qgis

Tags: python, osgeo

My python installation is a mess.
Therefore I'd like to reinstall the entire installation of it. (Unfortunately,) I've also installed QGIS and PyCharm (mostly making it a mess) and I want to start clean..!

So, what is the best way to get rid of every little python thingy and what are the best packages/methods for reinstalling Python27, QGIS and PyCharm? Should I go for osgeo or not, should I first install Pycharm or Python etc. Hopefully you have some good thoughts and tools on this. I'm a fan of pip, so in the end I hope its possible just to use pip for installing the packages all around.

I'm working on Windows 7, 64bit (thanks for the headsup Karel)

Answer (score 0):

Go to add/remove programs in windows and uninstall everything.  Then reinstall everything.  Do your Python install first and PyCharm should detect everything.  I'd suggest doing the 32 bit Python install as some packages aren't compiled for 64 bit and it makes things a bit challenging to find and install them.

Pip is standard in the python install now.  You'll see a check box in the installer for it, which is pre-checked.  I'd change your install directory to something simple like C:\Python27

Other than that it should be pretty straightforward.  However I doubt you really need to uninstall Python.  You can just go to settings and under the interpreter section add the C:\Python27 directory.  PyCharm is constantly scanning for installed modules, so it will know in real time that you've installed them.  You can even install packaged via PIP while PyCharm is open and within second PyCharm will recognize it as a valid package.

If you're missing packages you can also import them in PyCharm and when you get the red underline saying it's missing, hover your mouse over it and hit alt+enter and you'll get a menu to install it.